# How to resolve a JQuery promise based on the user input

Tags: jquery, promise, bootbox

I've got this code whose result should be returned as either resolved or rejected promise.

```
var runChecks = function(hasClickId, maxClicksModeIsNotOff) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    clickIdCheckPassed = hasClickId; // equals false
    maxClicksCheckPassed = maxClicksModeIsNotOff; // equals false

    if (!clickIdCheckPassed) {
        clickIdCheckPassed = runClickIdCheck();
    }

    if (!maxClicksCheckPassed) {
        maxClicksCheckPassed = runMaxClicksCheck();
    }

    if (maxClicksCheckPassed && clickIdCheckPassed) {
        dfd.resolve('Resolved');
    } else {
        dfd.reject('rejected');
    }

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Functions `runClickIdCheck()` and `runMaxClicksCheck()` collect user input and based on it, return either `true` or `false`. If both resulting values are `true`, I should resolve the promise, otherwise it should be rejected - hence the conditional:

```
if (maxClicksCheckPassed && clickIdCheckPassed) {
    dfd.resolve('Resolved');
} else {
    dfd.reject('Rejected');
}
```

However, the problem is that the code does not wait for the user input and each time evaluates the promise as 'rejected' even before the user gave any input.

For reference, this is how `runClickIdCheck` function looks like:

```
var runClickIdCheck = function() {
    bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result) {
        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

How I can make this code behave as expected, so that I evaluate the promise to 'resolve' only when the functions dependent on user input both return true?

**Edit:**

The expected UI behaviour is that the form should be submitted only if the user confirms the dialogue twice:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.when(runChecks(hasClickId, maxClicksModeIsNotOff)).then(
        function(status) {
            $form.submit()
        },
        function(status) {
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

This is why I thought the promise inteface would do the job. The promise shoudl be resolved if `runClickIdCheck()` and `runMaxClicksCheck()` evaluate to `true`.

Comment: I think you are misusing promises here. Your check seems entirely synchronous, so (even though it's possible) it's not really *necessary* to shoehorn it into promise semantics. Just run the check as and when you need to run it. Explain more about the problem you try to solve, i.e. what UI behavior are you trying to implement? Also add the necessary markup that demonstrates it.

Comment: @Tomalak Looks like `runClickIdCheck` method is async. OP should set logic in relevant callback or this plugin method (which i don't know) handles promise interface

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah, that's of course right.

Comment: @Tomalak, I've edited the question where I show the relevant callback and explain expected UI behaviour.

Comment: `runMaxClicksCheck()` works like `runClickIdCheck()`, i.e. as an bootbox dialog?

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, they're the same, only the confirmation message is different

Comment: And they should run in one after another, I presume...?

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

While *it's possible* to make this work with `$.Deferred()`, I doubt that it is worth it.

I have implemented a promise-based solution prior to writing the following code, and turned out to be a lot longer and a lot less clear than just using the callback-based approach that `bootbox` offers.

Keep it simple.

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    var self = this;

    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm('Question 1', function (confirmed1) {
        if (!confirmed1) return;

        bootbox.confirm('Question 2', function (confirmed2) {
            if (!confirmed2) return;

            $.post(self.action, $(self).serialize()).done(function (data) {
                // Ajax post has finished successfully
            });
        });
    });
});
```